# Create new list based on values taken from sublist

Tags: python, list

I have a list composed of a given number of sublists. I need to create a new (smaller) list by rejecting items in all sublists based on the values stored in the first one.
This is what a MWE of what I mean:

```
a = [[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
[0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29]]

b = [[] for _ in range(len(a))]
for indx, item in enumerate(a[0]):
    if item == 2:
        b[0].append(a[0][indx])
        b[1].append(a[1][indx])
        b[2].append(a[2][indx])
```

which results in:

```
[[2, 2, 2], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [0.27, 0.28, 0.29]]
```

This works, but I'm looking for a more pythonic way of creating my `b` list.

Comment: I can't see how input and output match your problem description. What do you mean by 'by rejecting items in all sublists based on the values stored in the first one'?

Comment: I'm creating `b` by rejecting elements in all sublists for which the element in the first one is equal to 2.

Comment: @LutzHorn: treat each nested list as a row, then match columns across rows. Pick the columns where the value in the first row is equal to two.

Comment: OK, but actually the values are not 'stored' in the first sublist but, as you describe in your answer, everything is *filtered*, including the first sublist.

Comment: Perhaps I expressed myself poorly. The values I use to filter the list are _stored_ in the first sublist, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the lists into columns, filter the columns, then use `zip()` again to transpose back to rows:

```
b = zip(*(col for col in zip(*a) if col[0] == 2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2], [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9],
... [0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29]]
>>> zip(*(col for col in zip(*a) if col[0] == 2))
[(2, 2, 2), (0.7, 0.8, 0.9), (0.27, 0.28, 0.29)]
```

This creates a list of tuples. Should you absolutely need lists, map to lists:

```
b = map(list, zip(*(col for col in zip(*a) if col[0] == 2)))
```

or, in Python 3, use a list comprehension:

```
b = [list(t) for t in zip(*(col for col in zip(*a) if col[0] == 2))]
```

Comment: Amazing one liner. I'm realizing `zip` is the answer to half of my issues, I need to learn to make better use of it. Thank you Martijn!

Comment: is there way similar  to `chain.from_iterable` but for zip?

Comment: Minor nitpick: I notice that the sublists in the new list are stored as _tuples_ instead of lists. Can this be modified to save lists or is this not an issue?

Comment: @Gabriel: map to lists: `map(list, zip(...))`.

Comment: @oleg: Not certain I am following you; there is no `zip.from_iterable`, but I cannot see what the usecase would be anyway.

Comment: why one should use `chain.from_iterable(iterable)` instead of `chain(*iterable)`

Comment: @oleg: because `*iterable` will consume the whole iterable, which is not always desireable. However, `zip()` *has* to see all iterables, otherwise it could not take columns from each.